# Distinct elements in priority queue

Tags: scala, priority-queue

I am using this implementation of a bounded priority queue, https://gist.github.com/ryanlecompte/5746241, and it works perfectly. However, I want this queue to not contain any element with the same ordering 'ord'. How can I achieve this?

I tried to update the maybeReplaceLowest function by giving the function lteq instead of lt.

```
private def maybeReplaceLowest(a: A) {
    if (ord.lteq(a, head)) {
      dequeue()
      super.+=(a)
    }
  }
```

But I think it does not work because the element which has the same ord as the new element might not be at the head. What could be a quick workaround for this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scala [PriorityQueue](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/PriorityQueue.html) is implemented using `Array`. Which is very inefficient for lookup operation, which you need to do for every insert (to check if the element already exists in the queue.

For [TreeSet](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/TreeSet.html) is ideal for lookup and ordered storage. 
But since this is a sealed class (scala-2.12.8) I created composite class

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class PrioritySet[A](val maxSize:Int)(implicit ordering:Ordering[A]) {
    var set = mutable.TreeSet[A]()(ordering)

    private def removeAdditional(): this.type = {
        val additionalElements = set.size - maxSize
        if( additionalElements > 0) { set = set.drop(additionalElements) }
        this
    }

    def +(elem: A): this.type = {
        set += elem
        removeAdditional()
    }

    def ++=(elem: A, elements: A*) : this.type = {
        set += elem ++= elements 
        removeAdditional()
    }

    override def toString = this.getClass.getName + set.mkString("(", ", ", ")")
}
```

This can be used as

```
>>> val set = new PrioritySet[Int](4)
>>> set ++=(1000,3,42,2,5, 1,2,4, 100)
>>> println(set)
PrioritySet(5, 42, 100, 1000)
```